# FlatList not working inside react native action sheet on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-actions-sheet

FlatList is no more scrollable with action sheet .

I followed documentation in which it suggest to import FlatList from action sheet package but when i load data of more than 100 users it crashes .
pls anyone who sol. share it.....

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing a lot of context, so I'll have to make a few assumptions to provide you with an answer. I see you're new here, so here is a post about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will make you get good answers more quickly and more often.

Lets continue: first of, I'm not sure what loading data from 100 users means exactly on your context, nor do I know the kind of information you're trying to show on the `Action Sheet`, but I'll be assuming that loading the *users* **data** is not what is causing the crash.

### Reconsider your approach

To be honest, I would never add so many itens inside an `ActionSheet`, even if it didn't crash. Here's why:

Even though from the developer standpoint it might seem like it achieves the goal of presenting every option to the user, it's really bad from a **user experience** standpoint:

1. Action sheets don't usually take the whole screen, so the user doesn't have much space to scroll through and read all the options;
2. Action sheets don't usually have search fields, so the user is locked in a small portion of the screen (1) trying to find one option among a hundred.

This is the kind of experience that makes users give up using your app.

### What I would do instead

You could you use the [`Modal`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal) component to create a component that will overlap your screen while `visible=true`, and inside such modal you could render a normal `FlatList` (imported from `react-native`). Also, for so many rows, you could also add a `TextInput` to that `Modal`, where the user could filter the results based on some text value.

(If you have trouble handling the input inside the modal, you can try [`KeyboardAvoidingView`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview))

This will make the user experience much better and you most likely won't be facing this crash issue.

Hope this helps!